# How can I use service in a helper class in nest.js?

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs

I import the redis module in `app.module.ts` file:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypegooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://mongo:27017/test', {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    }),
    RedisModule.register({ url: 'redis://sessions' }),
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I would like to create a helper class `SessionManager` that would manage user's sessions (store, update, delete them in Redis), e.g something like this:

```
import { RedisService } from 'nestjs-redis';
import { User } from 'src/users/schemas/user.schema';
import { IUserSessions } from '../interfaces/Session.interface';

class SessionManager {
  constructor(private redisService: RedisService) {}

  saveUserSession(user: User, userAgent: string) {}

  static getSessionsByUserId(userId: string): IUserSessions {
    const client = this.redisService.getClient()
    const sessions = client.hmgetall(userId)

    return sessions
  }
}

export default SessionManager
```

and use it in my `auth.service.ts`. How do I do that? Does it have to be represented as some Nest.js entity (module or provider)?

Comment: you just have to export the service from the RedisModule and then import the Module in the module which has the SessionManager as a provider

Answer (score 1):

Ended up creating a separate `sessions` module, adding my service as a Provider and exporting it, then using it in my desired module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SessionsService } from './sessions.service';

@Module({
  providers: [SessionsService],
  exports: [SessionsService]
})
export class SessionsModule {}
```